# Kerberos Authentication only works on IE -> Private Browser

Tags: internet-explorer, single-sign-on, kerberos

I am new into an IT Operations support job.  We have an application that sits on a windows 2012 web server that speaks to a oracle 12.2 database that resides on a seperate server.

The issue is that we migrated our application to a new version.  Old PROD version to new PROD Version.  our company uses kerberos to authenticate SSO.  We are seeing an issue where some users who were users of the old version are unable to login with internet explorer to the new version after the migration.  This doesn't effect all previous users.  For instance myself and another person were previous users of the old production and after the migration we have no issue with sso'ing into the new production.

The users who face the issue are only able to successfully login to new PROD if they use InPrivate browser of Internet Explorer.  If they attempt to use Chrome, or Chrome incognito, they get an issue and the applications UI states "invalid kerberos token".  But again, if they use IE-InPrivate browser, they get success.

our company has a tight hold on access security settings in IE browser, but can anyone give some insight on why this issue would occur so sporadically and randomly to some users???  I know its a total shot in the dark but I am just throwing up a hail mary to get some guidance on where to look maybe.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a good chance the kerberos tickets they're using are cached. Try `klist purge` from a command line and retry within a normal browser session.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could try to configure some options to make the browser support for Kerberos.

> Most PingFederate SSO connections will use the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) in SSO URLs, so it will not be categorized as being in the Intranet zone.  As such, the browser must be configured trust the host by adding the PingFederate hostname to the Trusted sites zone.
>
> On computers (i.e: servers) with Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration enabled the automatic login behavior will be overridden with a logon prompt. The logon prompt will allow Kerberos and NTLM logon functionality however it will not use the cached credentials from the user login.

You may try the following steps in IE to make it work.

- choose Tools → Internet Options → click the Security tab → click on Trusted sites →and click Custom level
- Scroll all the way to bottom under User Authentication and under Logon → select Automatic logon with current user name and password.
- click on the Sites button under Trusted sites → insert the server's hostname.

Google Chrome in Windows will use the Internet Explorer settings, so maybe this setting will also work in Chrome.

For more about how to configure supported browsers for Kerberos, you could refer to:
https://ping.force.com/Support/PingFederate/Integrations/How-to-configure-supported-browsers-for-Kerberos-NTLM